# are toyota land cruiser's tires made of special material?

Tags: toyota, tires, land-cruiser

How is it that Toyota land cruiser can go to almost any road with big stones and sharp nails , etc  and nothing happens to its tires. why? are its tires special and different from ordinary cars?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What year in particular are we talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, more plies and a heavier load rating , also the tread pattern and thickness play a part - the 4x4 designed for work have such tyres but 4x4 sold as "chelsea tractors" that is , those 4x4 that have never seen a muddy field , towed a trailer or even never been in low range : such as range rovers mercedes etc etc all covered in bling will have a tyre with a higher speed rating which are not as strong.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of conjecture here. Could you please provide sources for what you've stated?

Comment: This link should help you with the differences : http://www.rangerovers.net/outfitting/tires/classictires.html

Comment: It's not me who needs help. It's the Mech community who deserves it. If you worked your answers towards that end, they'd be a LOT more accepted. Besides, your single link doesn't go very far to prove all the conjecture you've written, which is actually most all of it.

Comment: You say conjecture - having owned landrovers both old series 2 and 3 and discovery and driven many vehicles as an agricultural contractor in many conditions with a huge variety if loads I based most of my answer on actual experience.......

Comment: In what manner do you believe tread pattern plays a part? I mean, tread thickness of course matters but tread pattern? I don't believe it.

Comment: @juhist some patterns are more likely to pick up and trap stones.... which can then lead to punctures...

Comment: Offroad tires have tread patterns with a lot more space between the blocks, to postpone the point where the tread spaces fill up and the tire becomes a slick. Sand tires have different patterns again.

Comment: So, as I pointed out in my reply, tread pattern plays a part...

Answer (score 1):

This is not Toyota-specific. For all serious off-road vehicles you can get tires [optimized for off-road use](https://www.carolinaclassictrucks.com/blog/the-difference-between-off-road-tires.html). And it goes further: you can get tires that are optimized for a specific terrain. Loose sand needs a different tire than snow or mud.

What these tires have in common is a sturdier construction: e.g. thicker rubber, more steel cord layers, reinforced sidewalls.
On-road tires usually have 2 steel cord layers. Off-road tires can have as many as 6. Note that this is not the same as the [ply rating](https://www.tirerack.com/tires/tiretech/techpage.jsp?techid=55).
Off-road tires also usually have [high sidewalls](http://www.overlandexperts.com/docs/articles/offroad_tire_taller_or_wider.pdf), to allow the tire to be compressed when driving over rocks, without the rock edge hitting the rim. On-road tires have low sidewalls to improve handling.

This sturdy construction makes the tire heavy, which is undesirable when traveling on-road at high speeds. It also compromises the handling: deep tread and high sidewalls means the car moves around on the tires.
So 4x4 vehicles that are used mainly on-road have [road-biased tires](http://www.toyotires.ca/blog/deciding-highway-all-terrain-or-road) built to withstand high speeds, at the cost of reducing their off-road capability a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the only possibility here is increasing the thickness of the tread and the sidewalls. This of course increases rolling resistance, which explains why such tires are not more widely used in regular cars.

If there was a special magic material that can resist punctures better than materials used in ordinary tires, such material would very quickly find much use in those ordinary tires. Especially interested would be bicyclists that have much thinner treads and sidewalls than car tires.

I know there are some bicycle tires that are advertised as puncture resistant. Usually they either include Kevlar fabric which does not offer any more protection against punctures than a Kevlar bulletproof vest offers against knife attacks. Or alternatively they include just more rubber in the tread and perhaps thicker sidewalls, which can actually help but result in tremendously increased rolling resistance.

I suspect if the Land Cruiser tires are really as puncture resistant as the poster of the question believes, they probably use the second strategy, i.e. thicker tread and sidewalls.

It would be interesting if somebody with a Land Cruiser could post the exact details of tires installed to the car. Tire manufacturers usually advertise the tread depth, so it could be compared to the tread depths of some ordinary tires.

Comment: After going from normal bike tires to puncture-proof tires (with kevlar), my number of punctures/yr has gone from several to 0.

Comment: @Hobbes I suspect the puncture-proof tires are just thicker, meaning increased rolling resistance. Oh, and I have used thin puncture-proof tires (Conti UltraGatorSkin), and they don't eliminate punctures according to my experience.

Comment: puncture-proof tires don't necessarily have higher rolling resistance, see e.g. https://www.fietsersbond.nl/de-fiets/onderdelen/banden/bandentest/ (in Dutch, sorry)